# How to render the following TeX (LaTeX) HTML string in my web application?

Tags: javascript, html, latex, katex

The title is pretty general but I have a bit of a specific question.

I'm given a database of TeX, in both raw and HTML form. Here are some examples:

Raw TeX:

```
Is there a number `a` such that `$\displaystyle  \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{3x^2 + ax + a + 3}{x^2 + x - 2}$` exists? If so, find the value of `a` and the value of the limit.
```

The same question in HTML:

```
<p> Is there a number <code>a</code> such that <code class='latex inline'>\displaystyle  \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{3x^2 + ax + a + 3}{x^2 + x - 2}</code> exists?
     If so, find the value of <code>a</code> and the value of the limit.</p>
```

I want to display this on my web application, but I'm having difficulties finding which library I'm supposed to use to render these in. I don't know where the `<code class='latex inline'>` comes from. Can anybody identify where it's form and how to render them? I've been trying to use KaTeX with no avail.

Comment: Hi. You can not as you do. *code* is a ignored tag by default. You need to change options. See ignored tags: **This is a list of DOM node types to ignore when recursing through. The default value is ["script", "noscript", "style", "textarea", "pre", "code", "option"].** read: [Katex autorender API](https://katex.org/docs/autorender.html#api)

Answer (score 0):

If you only mean to display tex expressions on your web app, maybe you would be interested in MathJax ?
Including the following lines in your html allow you to write something like :

```
\[ <some_tex_expression> \]
```

and get a good rendering.

Lines to include :

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script> 
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3.0.1/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
```

Now if you want to write inline maths between $ symbols, you just have to add a few lines in the script. The Mathjax documentation is clear and explains how to perform this.